# Start and stop PHP-FPM for specific users in a pool

Tags: php, ubuntu, nginx

I've set up a lemp stack, and intended to have each system user have their own isolated php-fpm instance to run their individual virtual hosts. I setup php-fpm pools for 2 test virtual hosts, and php pages load and everything seems to work, but Im not sure I've implemented this correctly.

My goal is to have it so I can control each php users php-fpm processes independently. Ideally, if one users configuration changes, and requires a PHP-FPM restart, I want only that users php-fpm instance to start / stop.

With my current implementation, I have to restart the php-fpm service, but in doing so that impacts every user on the system, not just the user that needs the restart.

My question is two part:

1. Am I missing something about how to control the php-fpm pools that are created? Is there a way to start/stop/restart the php-fpm pools on a per user basis? How?
2. If that is not possible, is there a way, tutorial, script, etc anyone can point me to that would allow me to start up multiple instances of php-fpm (1 for each user with its own configuration?)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can run two php-fpm instance at the same time, for example I run two version of php-fpm on the same server.

In your case you can run two instance with the same version, but you have two config the php-fpm service and config, data path of the second instance.

```
ps -aef | grep php-fpm | grep master
root      2375     1  0 Sep14 ?        00:02:19 php-fpm: master process (/etc/php/8.1/fpm/php-fpm.conf)
root     32499     1  0  2022 ?        00:13:32 php-fpm: master process (/etc/php/7.3/fpm/php-fpm.conf)
```

```
 ss -l | grep php
u_str              LISTEN              0     128    /run/php/php7.3-fpm.sock 73200768                                                    * 0
u_str              LISTEN              0     128    /run/php/php8.1-fpm.sock 393263343                                                   * 0
```

Comment: Right. But how do I control the processes on a per user basis? Right now, I have pools running. I need to be able to start/stop/restart either the pools on a per user basis, or the individual instances on a per user basis, the challenge I have is how to accomplish either of those things without affecting other users.

Comment: Run php-fpm instance1 for the first user, then instance2 for the second user.

Comment: Im still not following. So I have php 7.4 - 8.2 fpm all running ont he same machine already. They serve pages just fine. How do I start a second php8.2-fpm that is specific to a user? PHP8.2-FPM currently is running as root, how would I make it run as rick? Then assuming that happens, how do I start and stop the service specific to the user rick?